# To install pgfplots for OSX Yosemite?

Tags: macos, latex

Old discussion about this topic for OSX Lion [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/87291/13173).
However, I think there is no good answer to this topic, since *pgfplots* is not already installed so not only a .sty file problem, like Alan writes there.

I am trying to run this script [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/161951/13173) but get the error about the missing *pgfplots*, after the generation of the *Liste.dat*:

[image]

I run `ls /usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/scripts/pgfplots/` and get

```
matlab2pgfplots.m   pgf2pdf.sh  matlab2pgfplots.sh  pgfplots.py.
```

This suggests me that have the command but the error is internal in `pgfplots`.

I reinstall the system and run the command `sudo tlmgr install --reinstall pgfplots` but I get the some error message as above.

**How can you install pgfplots in OSX Yosemite?**

Comment: Ah, the screenshot output is missing some crucial things, just run pdflatex from the command line to see the full output. This looks like the package is installed fine but the example doesn't work -> might be better to follow up on the TeX site with this.

Answer (score 2):

`pgfplots` is available as part of [MacTeX](https://www.tug.org/mactex/):

[image]

---

To forcefully reinstall it from the command line, you can use

```
sudo tlmgr install --reinstall pgfplots
```